# docx file corruption using byte stream and Dropbox API

Tags: api, dropbox, docx, xlsx

We have a web app that allows users to upload files to their Dropbox account. This web app uses the Dropbox API to facilitate the upload process. After upload, when a user tries to view file type .docx it gives a message, "The file "somefile.docx" cannot be opened because there are problems with the content".

Here is some of the code we are using:

First, we are converting the file to a byte[] and passing it into the API method call.

```
public static string DropboxUpload(byte[] DBbyte, string filename, string token, string tokensecret)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var dropclient = new RestClient(FILEURL);
                dropclient.ClearHandlers();
                dropclient.AddHandler("*", new JsonDeserializer());

                dropclient.BaseUrl = FILEURL;
                dropclient.Authenticator = new OAuthAuthenticator(dropclient.BaseUrl, API_KEY, API_SECRET, token, tokensecret);

                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.Resource = VERSION + "/files/dropbox" + PATH;
                request.AddParameter("file", filename);

                request.AddFile(new FileParameter { Data = DBbyte, FileName = filename, ParameterName = "file" });

                var response = dropclient.Execute(request);

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    break;
                else
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);   
            }

            string dropboxLink = GetPublicLinks(filename, token, tokensecret);
            dropboxLink = dropboxLink.Replace("\"", "");
            return dropboxLink;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

The response from the api is
{ "Winner!"}
We have also verified that the byte[] is not corrupted before it is sent to Dropbox.

Then when a user tries to open the file either by downloading it from the website or just viewing the file directly from the Dropbox folder, they get this error message.
[image]

This is happening for .xlsx (Excel 2007 - up) files as well.
Files of type .docx and .xlsx are being corrupted when they are uploaded to the Dropbox folder by the Dropbox API? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this also the case with "simple" files - like *.txt?

Comment: What happens when you compare the original file with the file in dropbox? Where are the changes? The end? The beginning?

Comment: Pablo, I used Winmerge to compare the original file and the file in dropbox. There seems to be a difference when I compare them in either .docx form or .xml form but the difference appears to be just style. Also I wanted to mention that I am using RestSharp's RestClient object to send http requests. I am assuming that works fine because it is widely used in .net just like asihttprequest is widely used on iOS.

Comment: Pablo, We looked at the file difference between the original file and the file in dropbox. The file in dropbox has a crlf at the end of line on the last line, where as the original file has nothing at the end of the last line.

Comment: Does anyone have a working example or tutorial on how to use the c# third party SDKs suggested here https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk ? I am still not able to correctly view Microsoft office 2007 - 2010 files that have been uploaded to dropbox using the dropbox rest api.

Comment: Pablo, We updated our code to use this open source library "DropNet" This library uses an updated RestSharp dll. This seems to have removed the extra carriage return. When I do a diff on the original file and the uploaded file, they are identical according to WinMerge. When viewing the file that has been uploaded, a dialog window (above screenshot) appears. When I click OK, another dialog window appears. When I click Yes, I get the file to appear correctly! However it opens as Document1[Compatibility Mode]. Has anyone tried working with the Dropnet library? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

.docx files and other office 2007 file types have this issue online. Have you checked your server MIME types (edit - if it uses your server as an in-between)?